# Generating webservice for my work in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, servlets, wsdl

I want to generate webservice is WSDL. I created the webservice in JSP and servlet. So when I search for a webservice the request to be handled by the servlet and the servlet should search the WSDL to get the available services which I described in my project.

For Example

JSP:   SHOW THE BEST CARS FROM THE SEDAN CATEGORY

SERVLET: GETPARAMETER: REQUEST:

Here I want to create WSDl for 3 car companies. In that companies WSDL file I must create the specifications and methods to give the results.

like COMPANY 1 WSDL:  SEDAN,SUV,MUV

COMPANY 2 WSDL:  SEDAN,SUV,MUV

COMPANY 3 WSDL:  SEDAN,SUV,MUV

But I googled a lot and got lot of tutorials to generate wsdl file creation for webservice and client creation. And also It showed only how to test the client and webservice. Now my question is how to generate wsdl related to my need.

How to create WSDL webservice for 3 car companies ?

How to use servlet to call these webservices?

I need some nice idea how to start this.

Thanks

Ameer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Services can be created in a couple of ways:

1) Top-Down approach (where we will create the WSDL file and then genereate the java files. not preferred for you since it seems you a beginner in this)

2) Bottom-Up approach (where you will create a simple dynamic web application and write all your java code. Then using the New -> Web-service option(In Eclipse IDE), you will generate the WSDL. This approach is preferred for a beginner)

Once the WSDL is created, you can use it in your project.

Please specify the type of Web service you are trying to create as well as the tool/IDE you are using for creating web service. The generation of WSDL file varies from one tool/IDE to other.

Regards,

Comment: Dynamic Webproject and Eclipse Juno